# Google custom search customizing

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-search

I know there are many posts on this subject but reading through them and testing out the code does not help with the issue I'm having.  I'm trying to make the search box smaller in size so I can add it to my menu bar.  I'm able to make the search box smaller but the button is far from the input box.  I tried changing the widths of the "TD" tag for that row and it didn't fix it.
I'm doing my testing on a regular aspx page till I get it configured correctly then add it to my master page.

test.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var cx = '##############################';
      var gcse = document.createElement('script');
      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
      gcse.async = true;
      gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();    
  </script>  
  <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>    
</asp:Content>
```

css

```
.cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2,
input.gsc-search-button-v2 
{
  height: 15px !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  min-width: 13px !important;
  padding: 5px 5px !important;
  width: 20px !important;    
}

input.gsc-input {    
  width:180px !important;    
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif !important;
  font-size:x-small !important;
  color:purple !important;
}

td.gsc-input 
{    
  width:180px !important;    
}

.gsc-input-box, .gsc-input-box-hover, .gsc-input-box-focus 
{
  border-color: #00ff90 !important;
  width:200px !important;
}

table.gsc-search-box 
{
  border-spacing: 0 0  !important;
}
```

I have honestly searched and looked at many articles and I'm still unable to get the correct combination of changes to make this display correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend to use browser developer toolbar to change the inline CSS style & test. Whichever style works, fix it in your style sheet.

Comment: Thank you Arun.  For now I'm using the full size version of the search bar.  I'm hiding it in a div and displaying it at the top when the search button is selected.   Thank you again.